# How to fix wxWidgets not found and json/json.h not found issues while installing guayadeque

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster

Documenting 2 issues I've faced during installation of Guayadeque on RPi4

1. wxWidgets not found

> -- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (MESSAGE):
> wxWidgets not found!

2. json/json.h not found

> h: No such file or directory  #include "json/json.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

1. Install these dependencies to resolve both the issue

   `sudo apt install libindicate-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libtag-extras-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libwxsqlite3-3.0-dev libwxbase3.0-dev build-essential git libcurl4-openssl-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev cmake libwxgtk-media3.0-dev gettext libwxgtk3.0 libjsoncpp-dev`
2. Build. Takes more than 30 mins.

   `./build`
3. Install on Raspbian

   `sudo make install`

*There might be some unused dependencies here, which you can remove with `sudo apt autoremove`.*